# Spring JPA merge - ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

### Spring Data JPA Merge Failure - ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

I am trying to save a entity to the DB,The entity has a composite Primary key

1. Unique Identifer Number
2. Date
3. A boolean flag

I have a restful API built to serve the above mentioned functionality.

My JPA Repository interfaces and classes:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface customRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  void refresh(T t);

  void merge(T t);

}
```

---

```
public class customRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
    implements customRepository<T, ID> {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public customRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void refresh(T t) {
    entityManager.refresh(t);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void merge(T t) {
    entityManager.merge(t);
  }
```

I am trying to merge the entity in my service class using:

```
 myEntities.forEach(myEntity -> {
          customRepository.merge(myEntity);
        });
```

When I make the API call to save the entities, I am seeing the below mentioned exception.

---

```
    "stack_trace":"org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: 
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; 
actual row count: 0; expected: 1; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: 
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; 
actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

---

Does jpa's merge uses batch update for persisting an entity? 
And since I am making multiple `merge()` calls, by iterating over the entities, Does the transaction created for each `merge()` call is abruptly ending before the next `merge()` call?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to me that you modified one or more parts of the composite key before the merge.

Comment: I have not modified the composite key before the merge, but a record with the same composite key structure must have been present in the DB already, even in this case the merge should ideally look in to the DB, if the record is already present, before persisting the entity.